# Does order matter when multiplying binomial coefficients?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I seem to have come across two problems with posted solutions that yield different answers.

> How many ways are there to split a dozen people into 3 teams, where
>   one team has 2 people, and the other two teams have 5 people each?

The posted solution for this problem is to say that there are 
$$\binom{12}{5}\binom{7}{2}\frac{1}{2}$$
Because we have 12 people to choose a group of $5$ from, then 7 people to choose a group of $2$ from. The $\frac{1}{2!}$ is there because we don't care which group of $5$ was chosen `first`.

On the other hand

> How many ways are there to deal 3 players 5-card hands from a standard deck?

The posted solution is 
$$\binom{52}{5}\binom{47}{5}\binom{42}{5}$$
because we have 52 cards to assign to the first hand, 47 for the second, and 42 for the third.

My question is this: why do we not divide by $\frac{1}{3!}$ like we did in the above? It seems like we should want to divide by the number of ways to arrange each players hand in order, since we don't care about order? 
Is one of these solutions wrong, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You always have to think through what symmetry is present (or absent).  In the first problem, there is a symmetry (switch the $2$ person teams).  In the second, there is no symmetry (Dealing me a Royal Flush in spades is not the same as dealing you a Royal Flush in spades).

Comment: Hmm, I sort of see that, could you explain a little more?

Comment: We do care about the order it seems. If the players are $A,B,C$ we count it different if $A$ and $B$ swap hands for example.

Comment: Okay, so if you multiply binomial coefficients $B_1*B_2$ you are saying there is an order ?

Comment: For the first problem, If I said "how many ways are there to assign players to teams $A,B,C$ with $2$ going to $A$ and $5$ each going to $B,C$?"  then I'd have broken the symmetry.  Now you can't switch $B,C$ because I have distinguished them.

Comment: @lulu great thank you! I see now. I think I misunderstood order here

Comment: No, never-mind, I don't get it. In both problems we are using the abstract word player and team, which seem exchangeable.

Comment: @lulu we didn't say player A,B,C in the second problem, so your comment above doesn't seem like an appropriate comparison

Comment: This is a problem of English, not Math.  When you invoke a poker game we imagine that there are players are can be distinguished from one another .  Thus dealing a Royal flush in Spades to player $1$ is different from dealing it to player $2$.  But, it's your problem.  You can specify that you want the players to be indistinguishable.  In that case, you would indeed divide by $3!$.

Comment: @lulu so really it is the problem's fault. They should make it clear whether the players are distinguishable or indistinguishable. Thanks

Comment: Sure.  I think that most people would read it the way I did, but you are correct:  where there is ambiguity in the phrasing, it's up to whomever set the problem to clarify.  If this were a test-like situation, I would take care to state precisely whatever assumptions I was making.  Here, for example, I would state that in the first problem I assumed the teams to be indistinguishable (save for size) but in the second I assume the players to be distinguishable.

Comment: Here, the courses are manifestly distinguished.  Dessert $\neq $ salad.  I suppose one might argue that ice cream followed by salad is a different meal from salad then ice cream...but I think most people would not.  again, though, we're just debating phrasing. Not a math issue.

Comment: There;s worse ambiguity out there, by the way.  "toss a fair die six times, what is the probability of getting a $6$?"  is standard phrasing but it is ambiguous. Do you mean "exactly one $6$" or "at least one $6$"?  Very different problems.